# SQLite Java Local Path to Database

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, path, connection

i can't really understand how to use the local path for the database.

```
   private Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:\\Programmieren\\Workspace VS Code\\JavaSQLite\\sqlite\\user.db");
        System.out.println("Connected.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Not Connected.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
    return conn;
}
```

The Path of the .java file is E:\Programmieren\Workspace VS Code\JavaSQLite\src\database.java.
Would appreciate any help, thank you in advance :).

Comment: You can't really store the database in `src`, as `src` won't exist once the program is exported.  If you were to embed the database like this (and assuming SQLite supported it), it would be read-only.  This is a common issue for all programmers regardless of language, where to store produces of the app? Luckily, this is also something which has been generally solved through platform conventions. For example, Windows recommends `{user home}/AppData/{app name}`, macOS recommends `{user home}//Library/Application Support/{app name}` and Linux uses `{user home}/.{app name}`

Comment: Also note, this is horrible exception handling. "Print an error __and keep going like nothing is wrong__ is really bad. try `throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);` as content of a catch block when you don't want to think about it.